# Using value from allselected in a measure to filter rows in another measure

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I want to use the selected slicer value in string format to filter rows in a table in a visual.

So, I created the following measure:

```
SlicerVal = ALLSELECTED(Table[Column1])
```

The follow up measure is as follows:

```
TotalRows = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table),filter(Table, Table[Column2] = [SlicerVal]))
```

However.. This returns completely different data. When hardcoding the string value the correct data is returned, like in the example below:

```
TotalRows = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table),filter(Table, Table[Column2] = "A"))
```

Is there a way to convert the measure value to a string somehow, which can be used dynamically to correspond the string value filter to the selected slicer value?

Comment: Yes, but you need to show more details. Share some sample data and a clear description of what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
TotalRows = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table),filter(Table, Table[Column2] IN ALLSELECTED(Table[Column1])))
```

[**Question**: are you intentionally filtering on all selected elements from Column1 when applying a conditions onto Column2? I have no idea about your use-case, that's why -- for safety reasons -- I'm asking...]